# How to make Win10 to set new network name the same as adapter name

Tags: windows-10, networking

We have Windows IoT embedded to our device and it is connected to two networks. We have named network adapters according to usage (for this example DEVICE1_NET and DEVICE2_NET). When the network is connected, it gets name like Network1 but when the device on the other side of the network cable changes Windows creates new network profile with new name.

Unfortunatelly we have an old peace of SW which depends on network name so we need the network name to stay the same for the network adapter.

I know it is possible to change network name via registry but we want something more automated.

Is it possible to make Windows to name the ethernet network after network adapter or at least make the network name unchangeable for the network adapter?

Comment: Please elaborate: "_When the network is connected, it gets name like Network1 but when the device on the other side of the network cable changes..._", as that's expected behavior and AFAIK, there's no way around that. While the network names are saved in the Registry, and can be modified in the Registry, that's not going to stop new networks from being created due to endpoint/router on the other end of the connection changing, as that's expected behavior. _(You may be able to set the MACs & hostnames of the endpoint(s)/router(s) the same if they're not connected to a network at the same time)_

Comment: It is connected directly to control computer which controls the machine. Sometimes there is a problem with that computer so it is replaced. I don't know if we are able to change the MAC of it.